# evaluate mixed type with eval()

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have two date/time variables that contains list of the date/time values and another variable containing the list of operator to operate over the date/time variables. The format can be expressed as follows:

```
column1 = np.array([date1, date2,.......,dateN])
column2 = np.array([date1, date2,.......,dateN])
```

Both of the above variables of type Date/Time. Then I have the following variable operator that has the same length of column1 and column2:

```
operator = np.array(['>=','<=','==','=!',......])
```

I am getting "Invalid Token" with the following operation:

```
np.array([eval('{}{}{}'.format(v1,op,v2)) for v1,op,v2 in zip(column1,operator,column2)])
```

Any hint to get around this issue ?

-------------------EDIT----------------------

With some sample data and without eval I get the following output:

```
 np.array(['{} {} {}'.format(v1,op,v2) for v1,op,v2 in zip(datelist1,operator,datelist2)])


array(['2017-03-30 10:30:22.928000 <= 2012-05-23 00:00:00',
   '2011-01-07 00:00:00 == 2017-03-30 10:31:14.477000'], 
  dtype='|S49')
```

Once I bring in eval(), I get the following error:

```
eval('2011-01-07 00:00:00 == 2017-03-30 10:31:14.477000')
File "<string>", line 1
2011-01-07 00:00:00 == 2017-03-30 10:31:14.477000
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

----------------------EDIT & CORRECTIONS ----------------------------

Date/Time variables that I mentioned before are basically of type numpy datetime64 type and I am now getting the following issue while trying two date comparions with eval:

```
np.array([(repr(d1)+op+repr(d2)) for d1,op,d2 in zip(${Column Name1},${Operator},${Column Name2})])
```

The above snippet is tried over a table with three columns where ${Column Name1} and ${Column Name2} is of numpy.datetime64 type and ${Operator} is of string type. The result is as follows for one of the rows:

```
numpy.datetime64('2014-08-13T02:00:00.000000+0200')>=numpy.datetime64('2014-08-13T02:00:00.000000+0200')
```

Now I want to evaluate the above expression with function eval as follows:

```
np.array([eval(repr(d1)+op+repr(d2)) for d1,op,d2 in zip(${Column Name1},${Operator},${Column Name2})])
```

Eventually I get the following error:

```
NameError:name 'numpy' is not defined
```

I can assume the problem. The Open Source Tool that I am using is importing numpy as np whereas repr() returning numpy that it does not recognize. If this is the problem , how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Show part the string without the eval.

Comment: I did not understand  - "Show part the string". A more elaborated comment is requested.

Comment: Try to be helpful in your question.  Don't expect us to guess what strings given to `eval` look like.

Comment: '2011-01-07 00:00:00 == 2017-03-30 10:31:14.477000' is not a valid python expression.

Comment: How to compare date type in python using the comparison operator then ?

Comment: `numpy` has a `np.datetime64` dtype that makes value comparisons even easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime` objects can be compared:

```
In [506]: datetime.datetime.today()
Out[506]: datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 10, 43, 18, 363747)
In [507]: t1=datetime.datetime.today()
In [508]: t2=datetime.datetime.today()
In [509]: t1 < t2
Out[509]: True
In [510]: t1 == t2
Out[510]: False
```

Numpy's own version of datetime objects can also be compared

```
In [516]: nt1 = np.datetime64('2017-03-30 10:30:22.928000')
In [517]: nt2 = np.datetime64('2017-03-30 10:31:14.477000')
In [518]: nt1 < nt2
Out[518]: True
In [519]: nt3 = np.datetime64('2012-05-23 00:00:00')
In [520]: [nt1 <= nt2, nt2==nt3]
Out[520]: [True, False]
```

---

Using the `repr` string version of a datetime object works:

```
In [524]: repr(t1)+'<'+repr(t2)
Out[524]: 'datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 10, 47, 29, 69324)<datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 10, 47, 33, 669494)'
In [525]: eval(repr(t1)+'<'+repr(t2))
Out[525]: True
```

Not that I recommend that sort of construction.  I like the dictionary mapping to an `operator` better.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first post, I am getting the operator as a list of strings: operator = np.array(['<=','>=','!=']). How generate an expression with a combination of datetime24 and string type ? I though eval() would do the job

Comment: But you were creating a string expression that contained the `str` representation of the datetime objects.

Comment: Yes, I was, because I did not know how to evaluate the expression of mixed type: one is datetime type and the other is the string type. I used the format() and then eval() to evaluate. Eventually it did not work out.

Comment: Looks like you've found an unexpected problem with `eval(rept(<np.object))`.  The `repr` uses the class name, not the import as.  A quick solution would be to add a `import numpy` statement.  I don't think there's any harm importing both ways..

Comment: The issue is solved by eval(repr(t1).replace('numpy','np'))

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use python operator for this:

```
# import operators used
import operator
from operator import ge, eq, le, ne

# build a look up table from string to operators
ops = {">=": ge, "==": eq, "<=": le, "!=": ne}

import numpy as np

# used some numbers to simplify the case, should work on datetime as well
a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 3])
b = np.array([2, 3, 2, 1])
operator = np.array(['>=','<=','==','!='])

# evaluate the operation
[ops[op](x, y) for op, x, y in zip(operator, a, b)]
# [False, True, False, True]
```